# Today text missing in UIDatePicker on iPod

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uidatepicker

I have encountered a strange error on iPod touch . Actually on this device "today" day text is missing in UIDatePicker although on every other device its not an issue at all. Has someone encountered it before.

[image].

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.view.isOpaque = false

    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    datePicker.setValue(0.9, forKeyPath: "alpha")
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
}
```

Comment: try to change background and text color.

Comment: yeah I have tried that too. but no success.

Comment: Add runtime attributes in interface builder.textColor & highlightsToday to the datepicker

Comment: Try to set as it is default picker. Change background color once successfully shows today date.

Comment: what is the iOS version of this iPod??

Comment: actually its iOS 9.3

Comment: Well actually I figured out a way, although its strange:
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
did the trick. :)